# I get an error saying string return ' ' but I have a 0 there. Is it not going through the string?

Tags: python, string, indexing, numbers, python-turtle

Here is my code:

```
    import turtle
    def first_index(s):
      for i in range(len(s)):
        if not (s[i].isdigit()):
          return i 
       return None
    
    def go_to(s):
      if s[0] == 'G':
        comma_ind = first_index(s)
        first_arg = int(s[1:comma_ind])
        second_arg = int(s[comma_ind + 1:comma_ind + first_index(s[comma_ind + 1:])])
        turtle.goto(first_arg, second_arg)
    
    go_to('G10,10')
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs? Your help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Looks like your `return None` is not indented to the correct depth.

Comment: Also, if you are not returning anything from a function, by default it will return None. So you can remove `return None` line.

Answer (score 0):

Two issue:

- `first_index` should return the last index if a a non-digit character is not found
- When getting the second parameter, you're sending a partial string to the index function so you need to add the starting index of the string you passed

Try this code:

```
import turtle
#This gets the 
def first_index(s): 
    for i in range(1,len(s)): 
       if not (s[i].isdigit()): 
          return i 
    return len(s)-1  # reached end of string

def go_to(s):
  if s[0] == 'G':
    comma_ind = first_index(s)
    first_arg = int(s[1:comma_ind])
    second_arg = int(s[comma_ind + 1:comma_ind + first_index(s[comma_ind + 1:])+comma_ind])  # add comma index to returned index
    turtle.goto(first_arg, second_arg)

go_to('G99,99')

input()
```

Output

[image: Turtle]